# remap to a map calling getchar() internally

Tags: key-bindings

I want to extend the [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) Plugin to take some action after the jump. To explain to those who are not familiar with this plugin, I will use the following simplified example.

Say in a plugin *UsefulPlugin* the following map is defined:

```
function! s:Goto()
    let char = nr2char(getchar())
    return "f" . char
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <Plug>(goto) s:Goto()
```

which does almost the same as the unmapped `f`: jump to the next char input by `getchar`.

Now as a user, I want to define a map that uses `<Plug>(goto)` and after the user input the char, jump to that char and delete until end of line. 
*As an illustration: the effect of this mapping should be equivalent to*

```
function! s:GotoAndMore()
    let char = nr2char(getchar())
    return "f" . char . "D"
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> fD s:GotoAndMore()
```

**My question is: how can I achieve this with `<Plug>(goto)`?**

Comment: you are missing `<expr>` in the first example, is that intentional?

Comment: Can you call `s:Goto` from `s:GotoAndMore()`? Are they in the same script?

Comment: no, `s:Goto` is provided by another plugin. My intention is to extend `easymotion`. It uses a very complex internal function.

Answer (score 2):

This is hackish and I'm not sure how this works if `s:Goto` calls another script-internal function.

I assume that the `s:Goto()` is already defined in another script.

```
function! GotoAndMore()
    " Get the mapping for <Plug>(goto)
    redir => xx | silent map <Plug>(goto) | redir end
    " extract the function name (incl script number)
    let funcName = matchstr(xx, "<SNR>[^(]*")
    " create a funcref for it
    let Func = function(funcName)
    " return function return value with following "D" 
    return Func() . "D"
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> fD GotoAndMore()
```

Test thoroughly!

Comment: The "D" will be consumed by the `getchar()` inside `Func`

Comment: @LiuSha No, The function is called and returns a String. E.g. "fU", if you entered 'U'. Then 'D' is appended to the returned string. The result "fuD" is then returned by `GotoAndMore()`.

Comment: You are right, But what I am going to deal with is a function in `easymotion`. And the function not only returns the expression but also has a lot of side effects updating the display. This approach does not work. Anyway, thank you very much for your reply. This would be helpful for other scenarios. I upvoted your answer.